# I got different results for a while loop and for loop in python (check the codes)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

FOR THE FIRST CODE:

```
num = 1

while num<=100:
    if num%3==0 or num%5==0:
        continue

    print (num, end=" ")
    num+=1
```

OUTPUT: `1 2`

FOR THE SECOND CODE:

```
for num in range(1, 101):
    if num%3==0 or num%5==0:
        continue

    print (num, end=" ")
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 2 4 7 8 11 13 14 16 17 19 22 23 26 28 29 31 32 34 37 38 41 43 44 46 47 49 52 53 
56 58 59 61 62 64 67 68 71 73 74 76 77 79 82 83 86 88 89 91 92 94 97 98
```

Comment: Your first code is infinite. I'm not sure how you got `1 2` as output.

Comment: Invert condition in while loop and put result printing inside. You skip `num` increment

Comment: What @Austin said. In your if condition for the first statement you don't increment your counter before you continue so num%3 is always true and likely freezes your program after that.

Comment: @Austin It only `continue`s at a multiple of 3 or 5, which 1 and 2 are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add incrementation before you continue

```
num = 1
while num<=100:
    if num%3==0 or num%5==0:
        num += 1
        continue
    print (num)
    num+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `while` code in order to achieve same result. In your `while` loop if `num%3 == 0 or num%==5`, then the program not executing `num += 1`, so your program doesn't increment 1. You need to change like this:

```
num=0
while num <= 100:
    num+=1
    if num%3==0 or num%5==0:
        continue

    print (num, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not call increment 1 in the while loop inside the if statement, it never gets past 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's an infinite loop. Your program never terminates after it reaches num == 3. It goes to the if statement and the continue takes it back to the while check.

Answer (score 0):

Use below logic

```
        num = 1

        while num <= 100:
            if num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
                num += 1
                continue
            print(num, end=" ")
            num += 1
```